# Continuous capital run strings in sentence in one line preferably using reduce or map function in python

Tags: python

Here I am trying to get all the continuous capital letter strings in a sentence. I have tried the following which gives an output as 'LJ'

I haven't been able to figure out why it doesn't add `STRR` and `HLLJ` but it adds only `LJ` instead to the list. Does it assume `[""]` as a string.

```
reduce(lambda x ,y : x[-1] + (y) if y.isupper() or y.isspace() else x,"STRR hello HLLJ",[""])
```

My input is :
`STRR hello HLLJ` and I wish to get an output as `["STRR","HLLJ"]`

Test case : 
    `ABCD AAA lkjl JJJJJJ. Here it should give ["ABCD AAA","JJJJJJ"]`

Any help is appreciated.

**Using Reduce I came up with this Finally but its not efficient:**

`reduce(lambda x, y : x[0:len(x)-1] + [x[-1]+y] if y.isupper() or y.isspace() else x + [""] if not x[-1].strip() is "" else x,"STRR Hello HLLJ", [""])`

Comment: Is this an entry for an obfuscated Python contest?

Comment: No it isn't . I just wanted to possibly have mostly one line functions in my code . I have to find Longest capital run strings , Avg capital run strings and capital run length total.

Comment: Somehow, it seems relatively simpler to write `reduce(lambda x, y : x+y  if y.isupper() or y.isspace() else x, "STRR hello HLLJ").split()` instead. No juggling with lists and their elements inside the lambda.

Comment: Oh thats good. You could add that as an answer . But why does it not work adding to the last element in a list

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to figure out what's going on with the original expression before putting my variant as an answer. Later perhaps.

Comment: There is one test case where it might fail though . ABCD AAA lkjl JJJJJJ. Here it should give ["ABCD AAA","JJJJJJ"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding patterns in strings is what the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is for:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: re.findall("[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*", "ABCD AAA lkjl JJJJJJ")
Out[2]: ['ABCD AAA', 'JJJJJJ']
```

or, if you don't want to include capital letters that are part of another word, you can exclude them using [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
In [3]: re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*\b", "ABCD AAA Lkjl JJJJJJ")
Out[3]: ['ABCD AAA', 'JJJJJJ']
```

Caveat: This only looks for ASCII letters.

Comment: Nice, but IMHO, given OP's original condition `if y.isupper() or y.isspace()` it should probably be `[A-Z ]+` (A-Z or space).

Comment: @tobias_k: Good point, but simply adding the space to character class won't work properly since the match shouldn't start or end with a space. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular expression and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
>>> asd="HELLO worLD"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[A-Z\s]+",asd)
['HELLO', 'LD']
```

Explanation:

- `[A-Z\s]+` matches one or more subsequent captial letters or whitespace
- `findall` returns a list of all matches.

Comment: This regex would find `['HELLO ', 'LD']`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, another solution using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> s = "STRR hello HLLJ"
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(s, key=str.isupper) if k]
['STRR', 'HLLJ']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version using reduce which works as it should for input `"STRR Hello HLLJ"` it gives output `['STRR H', ' HLLJ']`. Its nice to get different ways to solve.

```
reduce(lambda x, y : x[0:len(x)-1] + [x[-1]+y] if y.isupper() or y.isspace() else x + [""] if not x[-1].strip() is "" else x,"STRR Hello HLLJ", [""])
```

I know this is not efficient.